# How to apply the same security properties of a login for all users login

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have defined security properties of a login

[image]

I have 200 users .
How can I apply dynamically the same security properties of a login for all users login ?

Comment: You can't via GUI. Try via sql script

Comment: Write T-SQL or PowerShell script. Tip: You can do it for one user using GUI and click `Script...` button and you know how to make script.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Role (through the GUI or T-SQL) with the required permissions, then add all 200 users as members of that role.  Not sure if you can force the role to 'copy' permissions from a particular user, but from an auditing and maintenance perspective, it's far simpler to make required changes to a Role once and have them instantly inherited by all members.